# Python script for google drive is redirecting to chrome authentication

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I write a python script to upload file to google drive, but the script is redirecting to chrome for email user authentication.
is there any way to avoid redirecting to chrome for authentication.
I'm running on python 3.9.
here is my sample code:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
gauth = GoogleAuth()           
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth) 

upload_file_list = ['myfile.pdf']
for upload_file in upload_file_list:
    gfile = drive.CreateFile({'parents': [{'id': '1B8ttlQMRUkjbrscevfa1DablIayzObh2'}]})
    # Read file and set it as the content of this instance.
    gfile.SetContentFile(upload_file)
    gfile.Upload() # Upload the file.
```

Comment: FYI, PyDrive is deprecated, and hasn't been updated since 2016. [PyDrive2](https://pypi.org/project/PyDrive2/) is the current version, or you can just use [`google-api-python-client`](https://pypi.org/project/google-api-python-client) directly.

Comment: How about using the service account?

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you are reporting is totally normal with OAuth 2.0 and the official Google APIs library.

What @Tanaike said is a good solution. You could use a service account to access Google Drive files without granting consent every time the token expires. With service accounts there are 2 options to achieve that:

1. Share the file/folder with the email address of the service account.
2. Use domain-wide delegation of authority to allow the service account to impersonate any user in your domain. Requires a domain using Google Workspace or Cloud Identity and Super Admin access to configure domain-wide delegation.

General information on how to make API calls with domain-wide delegation is available on this page https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests.

Here is a working code sample:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
 
# Scopes required by this endpoint
# https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"]

# Variable that holds the file ID
DOCUMENT_ID = "i0321LSy8mmkx_Bw-XlDyzQ_b3Ny9m74u"

# Service account Credential file downloaded with domain-wide delegation of authority
# or with shared access to the file. 
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = "serviceaccount.json";

# Creation of the credentials
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE,
    scopes=SCOPES)

# [Impersonation] the service account will take action on behalf of the user,
# requires domain-wide delegation of authority.
delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject('user@domain.com')

# The API call is attempted
try:
    service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=delegated_credentials)

    # Retrieve the documents contents from the Docs service.
    document = service.files().get(fileId=DOCUMENT_ID).execute()

    print('The title of the document is: {}'.format(document.get('name')))
except HttpError as err:
    print(err)
```

Keep in mind that to use user impersonation you will need to configure domain-wide delegation in the Admin console of the domain that has the files (this will also work for external files shared with users in the domain).

If you want to use this with regular consumer accounts you can't use user impersonation, instead you will share the file with the service account (read or write access) to later make API calls. Line 20 creates delegated credentials, this line needs to be removed if you will use this other approach.